# click on card to open 'details' view in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-model

I cannot find an example on how to make a ionic card clickable. The behaviour I want to implement is to be able to click on each card my app has (and has lots of them) and get a modal view open with more detailed information referring to the card contents.

I would prefer some kind of semi-transparent modal with a close button than a full screen one, but I cannot find a satisfactory method to do so also.

Can you please, post me some code to get some insight on how to do this?.

Thanks in advance,

Jose

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: I have tried http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPopup for the 'transparent' modal, which is right for me (although I would prefer a different look and feel with some frame...), but I cannot find anything for the clickable tab (the full tab, not an icon or image on it).

Comment: You can simply call method on click with `onClick` or `ng-click` where you open modal with detail.

Comment: I recommend you to visit codepen.io and search for "ionic modal". There are some nice examples to be found there.

Comment: Simple as that?!!. I have used that before, didn't know it was applicable to the whole card item... OMG... too new to this